# Merging arbitrary number of types from one generic type

Tags: typescript

I have the following situation:

I have a function that I want to be able to use on different objects and thus types.

For example lets look at this object:

```js
const obj = {
  foo: "some string",
  bars: [{ text: "some text"}]
}
```

I would like to call something like this `update(obj, operation)`

`operation` should only have the following possible types:

```js
type T1 = {
  path: "foo";
  value: string;
}

type T2 = {
  path: "bars";
  value: {text: string}[];
}

type T3 = {
  path: `bars[${number}]`;
  value: {text: string};
}

type T4 = {
  path: `bars[${number}].text`;
  value: string;
}
```

I managed to create a type that gives me the allowed path values for a given type:

```js
type PathString<T> = keyof {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends string | number | boolean
        ? `${K}`
        : T[K] extends string[] | number[] | boolean[]
        ? `${K}` | `${K}[${number}]`
        : T[K] extends (infer ArrayType)[]
        ?
                | `${K}`
                | `${K}[${number}]`
                | `${K}[${number}].${PathString<ArrayType>}`
        : T[K] extends Record<string, any>
        ? `${K}` | `${K}.${PathString<T[K]>}`
        : never];
};
```

But I do not know how I can merge possible types.

Is this even possible?

Comment: It's definitely possible but such deeply nested types always have bizarre edge cases and fixing them often involves completely refactoring your type.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wezqgN) meet your needs? If it does meet your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Please test carefully; I don't want to write up a huge explanation for something it then turns out you can't use)

Comment: It seems like this is exactly what I need, although I do not fully understand it yet.
I will need some time to play around it to fully understand.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you saying you need time to test if it works for you? Or just time to understand it?  If it's just to understand then I can write up an answer that should help you understand it. If you still need to test it against use cases then I'll wait.  How should I proceed?

Comment: It works exactly as it should, but I do not understand it completely. I would be very thankful for some input.

Comment: Okay I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deeply [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) tend to have lots of bizarre edge cases when you try to use them on varying real-world inputs, and sometimes changing the edge-case behavior requires a complete refactoring of the type. The approach I present below works for the example as given in the question, but I make no guarantee about its applicability to other situations (e.g., object types with [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties), or types with [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), or recursive types, etc).

---

First I'll create a type `PV<T>` which produces a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `path`/`value` pairs corresponding roughly to every dotted path in the object `T` and the corresponding property type at that path.  The difference here is that all these paths will end up prepended with a dot, which we'll peel off later:

```
type PV<T> = { path: "", value: T } | (T extends object ? (
  { [K in keyof T as (
    T extends readonly any[] ? `${Extract<K, number | `${number}`>}` : K
  )]: PrependPath<Exclude<K, symbol>, PV<T[K]>>
  } extends Record<string, infer U> ? U : never) : never);
```

where

```
type PrependPath<K extends string | number, PV> =
  PV extends { path: infer P extends string | number, value: infer V } ? {
    path: K extends number | `${number}` ? `[${K}]${P}]` : `.${K}${P}`;
    value: V
  } : never;
```

Before I explain how it works, let's see what it outputs:

```
type PVTest = PV<{ foo: string, bars: Array<{ text: string }> }>;
/* type PVTest = 
  { path: ""; value: { foo: string; bars: Array<{ text: string; }>; }; } | 
  { path: ".foo"; value: string; } | 
  { path: ".bars"; value: { text: string; }[]; } | 
  { path: `.bars[${number}]`; value: { text: string; }; } | 
  { path: `.bars[${number}].text`; value: string; } 
*/
```

So you see that this is what you want except it includes the null path, and all the paths are prepended with `.`.

---

Okay, so, there are a few pieces of `PV<T>`.  First we return `{ path: "", value: T }` corresponding to the empty path and the current value.  And if `T` is not an object type then we're done, since that's `{ path: "", value: T} | (T extends object ? ⋯ : never)`.

If `T` is an object then we have to get the path/value pairs for all of its properties as well, which we get by [mapping over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) all its properties of key `K` in `keyof T` to get a new object type and then using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to pull it out into a union.

Let's temporarily replace `PrependPath<Exclude<K, symbol>, PV<T[K]>>` with `〈K〉` to show that it's some type function of the `K` property.  Then we have something like

```
  { [K in keyof T]: 〈K〉 } extends Record<string, infer U> ? U : ever;
```

which ends up producing a union of `F<K>` for all `K` in `keyof T`.  Like this:

```
type Testing<T> =
    { [K in keyof T]: F<K> } extends Record<string, infer U> ? U : never;
type Foo = Testing<{ a: string, b: number, c: boolean }>;
// type Foo = F<"a"> | F<"b"> | F<"c">
```

So we have

```
 { [K in keyof T]: 〈K〉 } extends Record<string, infer U> ? U : ever;
```

except we also need to tweak *which* properties `K` we iterate over, because things are a little trickier for array types.  We don't want to iterate over array method names like `"push"`, but we do want to pull out the numeric [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) `number` key, as well as any numeric-like keys such as `"0"` and `"1"` if the array type is also a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).  So the mapping is actually more like

```
 { [K in keyof T as (
        T extends readonly any[] ? `${Extract<K, number | `${number}`>}` : K
    )]: 〈K〉 } extends Record<string, infer U> ? U : never;
```

where we use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to include all of the keys if `T` is not an array, or just the number-like keys if `T` is an array.

Okay now we need to describe `〈K〉` to produce the path/value pairs for the property at key `K` of `T`. Recall that it's actually `PrependPath<Exclude<K, symbol>, PV<T[K]>>`, so

```
 { [K in keyof T as (
        T extends readonly any[] ? `${Extract<K, number | `${number}`>}` : K
    )]: PrependPath<Exclude<K, symbol>, PV<T[K]>> 
 } extends Record<string, infer U> ? U : never;
```

So we are recursively evaluating `PV<T[K]>` and then essentially calling `PrependPath<K, PV<T[K]>>` to prepend the key `K` to the path.  Except that keys can be `string`s or `number`s or `symbol`s in TypeScript, and you can't concatenate `symbol` with [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html), so we need to write `Exclude<K, symbol>` (using [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers)) to suppress any `symbol` keys.

---

Finally we can look at the definition of `PrependPath`:

```
type PrependPath<K extends string | number, PV> =
  PV extends { path: infer P extends string | number, value: infer V } ? {
    path: K extends number | `${number}` ? `[${K}]${P}]` : `.${K}${P}`;
    value: V
  } : never;
```

Given an initial `string` or `number` path segment `K` and a union of path/value pairs `PV`, the `PrependPath` type produces another union for each member of `PV` via the [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) `PV extends ⋯ ? ⋯ : never`.

It does this by keeping `value` the same, but changing `path` depending on whether `K` is a numeric-like key or not.  If it is numeric-like, then we encase it in square brackets like `4` becomes `[4]` or `number` becomes `` `[${number}]` ``, but if not, then we prepend a dot to it like `a` becomes `.a`.

And that's all of `PV<T>`.

---

Now all we need to do is only take paths starting with `.` and remove that `.` character. So we will define `PathValues<T>` as:

```
type PathValues<T> = PV<T> extends infer PVT ?
  PVT extends { path: `.${infer P}`, value: infer V } ?
  { path: P, value: V } : never : never;
```

This will completely eliminate the empty path like `{path: "", value: T}`, and replace paths like `".foo.bar[1].baz"` with `foo.bar[1].baz`.

---

Okay, finally, let's test it out:

```
type V = PathValues<{
  foo: string, bars: Array<{ text: string }>
}>;

/* type V = 
  { path: "foo"; value: string; } | 
  { path: `bars[${number}].text]`; value: string; } | 
  { path: "bars"; value: { text: string; }[]; } | 
  { path: `bars[${number}]]`; value: { text: string; };} 
*/

type W = PathValues<{
  a: [boolean, string], b: { c: number }
}>;

/* type W = 
  { path: "a"; value: [boolean, string]; } | 
  { path: `a[${number}]]`; value: string | boolean; } | 
  { path: "a[0]]"; value: boolean; } | 
  { path: "a[1]]"; value: string; } | 
  { path: "b"; value: { c: number; }; } | 
  { path: "b.c"; value: number; }
*/
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-AD0ACooBb7dbbZhXDjuqQKF9dbTSI7neGYUdc57vX6A3ggyHPMXjrmYxxGyUM7gs+QVU6ZGRczT9aSI7CWzw25zsyry5Je3mB7Ww4OS43oiOoGOO6qp1KRQKfIq+3q6fPgPXh82WaPdJm8fFJ17JNvRXuoirQ8A4gf84uGyytPHY+a4CWt0cCHpIyCovaEHEnyBLFFaGjonAAgQny15cqqSRwbAVTUoe+IMhczKcOo643jAeFfsRxofDRpq-MoQS2vICh2myujdtmkgyHk0BukcVCuFOpD6MeXE8dAb5kBwURaOwgEAsymAgoQoG0uB7FQJx37ulAwlQP6gbBkmdY6XCUZySgZoJkmQFQEpa5Xu2N5kN2M79nS-GrmRGFbmUu6yq+nhRB+s6eUOpYXo5ejjuQU7ufhehvqekXsCuUU+cqfk7hUz4hZ+c4mQuXnNpwf4AX8dkAOp2ipanMBprh4CJcjOvQ-iiCMEVRB6BZQMopBPhwlnWYmyY1emTmxWQeAJV++itRMHVdSWUTeVNG54I+AVRPlYUpSUi3teE60xR2M36AADLtc0DkdHWneh2ZbQAjDdBXhUuGUbS5ci3Ue-WDbujaPc5XJkHIKrKP9QO5Y25W-EAA)